# can't do particular binary operation

Tags: javascript, binary

I wonder if there is a simple way to do the following with binary operation :

First byte : 
1001 1110

Second byte : 
0001 0011

Expected result :
1000 1100

I just want to  set all bits of the first byte to 0, where in the second byte, the bits are 1

Comment: It's possible. But in which language? And what have you tried?

Comment: I want to do it in javascript, I just tried in my head, but nothing simple passes, no simple xor etc...

Comment: Something like C = A&(!B) should work. I'm not familiar enough with bit operations in JavaScript though, tbh.

Comment: Put an answer with the correct NOT operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using XOR and AND operators like this:

> (A ^ B) & A

EDIT:
And as other mentioned you could use AND and NOT operators like this:

> A & (~B)

Comment: @AntonH Why not? XOR will make: 1000 1101 then AND will make it to 1000 1100 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have:

```
var a = 0x9E;
var b = 0x13;
```

To get your expected result, try:

```
var c = a&(~b);
```

Explaination: using the NOT(~) operator on B will give us your mask: `NOT 0001 0011` => `1110 1100`. Applying this mask to the variable `a` with an AND operator will set to 0 the desired bits per the variable `b`.